# How to end a header 3 box in rmarkdown beamer madrid presentation?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

When using the Madrid beamer theme (and some others) the Header 3 is rendered as a box covering the whole section, but in markdown the header is only specified at the start.  How can I specify the end of the section?

In the example below, I want the second sentence to be inside the box, but the third to be back on the white background.

**Example:**

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    colortheme: beaver
    theme: Madrid
---

## Slide with Box

Hello, I'm not in the box

### This is a box
And this text is in the box!


I don't want to be in the box, but I am.
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @zx8754 that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
## Slide with block 2

Hello, I'm not in the block.

\begin{block}{This is a block}
  And this text is in the block!
\end{block}


Hi, I'm not in the block either!
```

Comment: Clever - switching down to the LaTeX directly, the markdown then ignores the LaTeX and passes it through.  Perfect

Comment: It still works for me, can you be more specific on how it does not work? (OS, R version, RStudio version etc)

Answer (score 5):

With newer versions of Pandoc (I have 2.2.3.2), you can use fenced divs to enclose a block. Did not work for me previously with 1.6.

Thus, this would work:

```
## Slide with Box

Hello, I'm not in the box

::: {.block}
### This is a box
And this text is in the box!
:::

I don't want to be in the box, and I am not.
```

`::: {.block}` and `:::` delimit the block. See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2957

An advantage with respect to using `\begin{block}` and `\end{block}` is that you get to use markdown within the block.

Comment: This solution has the advantage, that you can use markdown within the block. **text** makes the word "text" bold. This does not work with plain LaTex